# How to give print option in a view page in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
<table class="table table-bordered admin-report" data-hook="sales_total">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= Spree.t(:currency) %></th>
      <th><%= Spree.t(:item_total) %></th>
      <th><%= Spree.t(:adjustment_total) %></th>
      <th><%= Spree.t(:sales_total) %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <% @totals.each do |key, row| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= key %></td>
        <td><%= row[:item_total].format %></td>
        <td><%= row[:adjustment_total].format %></td>
        <td><%= row[:sales_total].format %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The details mentioned the in post dont seem relevant to printing a page, suggest you to edit accordingly. Secondly, did you try executing `window.print()` through JavaScript on click on a button or link. That should give you the print dialog. or did i misunderstand anything?

Comment: It prints entire page i want only the table so i mentioned only table in the code mentioned here

Comment: http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/ may help you to print only a single element. or you may also try writing the table HTML to an iframe and print that iframe.